# How to call a method in a Fragment when backstack change

Tags: android, android-fragments, onresume, fragment-backstack

I have 2 fragments FragmentA and FragmentB

From FragmentA I open FragmentB

```
val transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
transaction.add(CONTAINER_VIEW_ID, FRAGMENT_B_INSTANCE, FRAGMENT_B_TAG)
transaction.addToBackStack(null)
transaction.commit()
```

User can back to FragmentA by both ways pressing a custom back button and pressing Phone back button. Custom button call the below method.

```
fragmentManager.popBackStack()
```

FragmentB is user adding form with API call, FragmentA onResume I call user list API and display user list. After add user in FragmentB and when back to FragmentA I need to call API again in FragmentA onResume or custom method in FragmentA to get latest users list.
(*FragmentA onResume won't call since not calling Activity onResume in this scenario*)

How can I do this?

Comment: There r multiple ways to do it depends on where r u loading data now. 
One ways is You can use [Fragment result API](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#fragment-result) to send back data weather to refresh of not.

Comment: @ADM I saw above answer already. It's not matching with my requirement. For better understanding I edited my question with more details.

Comment: I think this is Exactly what u need . So u only need to reload users in Fragment A if and only if there is new user added from fragment B .. So u can send a flag back to FragmentA whether to reload the data or not .. You don't have to rely on `onResume`..

Answer (score 0):

if your want dont want to come back to FragmentA then you have to remove from stack when you go to FragmentB. So, in this way move from FragmentA to FragmentB and to FramentC but on coming back from FragmentC to FragmentB not to FragmentA

Comment: It's not matching with my requirement. For better understanding I edited my question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

There are methods to call resume functions

> in Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onPostResume() {
    super.onPostResume();
}
```

> in Fragment

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}
```

Hope this works for resuming

Comment: Is this Fragment onResume call when popBackStack and back to FragmentA as my question?

Comment: I'll have to test it?

Comment: Fragment onResume never calls when back stack change. That's why I'm finding another solution.

Comment: onWindowsFocusChanged might work?